# Regex and .contains

Tags: kotlin

I am recognizing words from an Imageview using FirbaseVisionImage class. I want to determined a substring which has a regex pattern of `( "^\\d{6}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\$")` from the whole string from an Imageview, and then show the substring which has the regex pattern of `( "^\\d{6}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\$")` at a textview, however it won't work

```
                val rotatedBitmap = rotateBitmap(bitmap, 270f)
                val firebaseVisionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(rotatedBitmap)
                val firebaseVision = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                val firebaseVisionTextRecognizer = firebaseVision.onDeviceTextRecognizer
                val task: Task<FirebaseVisionText> =
                    firebaseVisionTextRecognizer.processImage(firebaseVisionImage)

                task.addOnSuccessListener { p0 ->
                    var s = p0?.text
                    val regex = Regex( "^\\d{6}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}\$")
                    var icFormat = ""
                    var subString = regex.matches(icFormat)
                    if(s!!.contains(subString.toString())){
                        binding.tvDemo.text = subString.toString()
                    }else{
                        binding.tvDemo.text = "Cannot Detect Regex"
                    }
                }
```

Comment: `var subString = regex.matches(icFormat)`, here `icFormat` is empty string, you `subString` would always be false.

Comment: `s!!.contains(subString.toString())`, subString is a boolean as `matches` return a boolean.